# How to prevent animation from repeating when app is reopened?

Tags: css-animations, nativescript-angular

I have implemented an animation in nativescript.

tns.html file

```
<StackLayout class="card">
    <Label text="Testing"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

tns.scss file

```
.card {
  animation-name: opacity;
  animation-duration: 2;
}

@keyframes opacity {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Every time I leave the app and then open it again, the animation repeats. How do I prevent the animation from repeating when the app is opened the second time?

Comment: by storing a boolean in webstorage (local or session as per your need) and add class using scripts accordingly. you might have event.preventdefault() kind of thing to not to apply card class if your boolean is true